# Revolving nested element around a center

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I made this animation of solar system after following codecademy's site : http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-ymqg0/0/1

I was able to get earth and moon to revolve, but after many trials too, the axis of the moon and astroid is not becoming properly. presently , this is my code :

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
#earth,
#moon,
#asteroid,
#sun {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#earth {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px blue;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -200px 0 0 -20px;
  -webkit-animation: Erevolve 12s linear infinite;
  animation: Erevolve 12s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 20px 200px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#moon {
  top: -30px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-animation: Mrevolve 2s linear infinite;
  animation: Mrevolve 2s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 5px 30px;
}
#asteroid {
  top: -10px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #aaa;
  -webkit-animation: Arevolve 2s linear infinite;
  animation: Arevolve 2s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 3px 10px;
}
#sun {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: gold;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px gold;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes Erevolve {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes Erevolve {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes Mrevolve {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes Mrevolve {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes Arevolve {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes Arevolve {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="earth">
    <div id="moon">
      <div id="asteroid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="sun"></div>
</body>
```

as you can see, the moon and asteroid are crashing into the earth. I dont know why this happens,

I also have calculated margin and height properly for transform origin property, without any luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using LESS or SASS?

Comment: Edward: no only html and css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.
http://jsbin.com/vemalo/1/

Your `top` margins are a little off.

Changes here https://www.diffchecker.com/3mdga45r

Answer (score 1):

```
#moon {
  top: -40px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-animation: Mrevolve 2s linear infinite;
  animation: Mrevolve 2s linear infinite;

}
#asteroid {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #aaa;
  -webkit-animation: Arevolve 2s linear infinite;
  animation: Arevolve 2s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 5px;
  overflow:none;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/luwenocola/2/